# Let $α = (156)(254)(34).$ Write $α^{1001}$ into a product of disjoint cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let α = (156)(254)(34).

Write α^1001 into a product of disjoint cycles.

[image]

Comment: First write $\alpha$ as a product of disjoint cycles, then think about what $\alpha^{1001}$ is. Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

First $(1\,5\,6)(2\,5\,4)(3\,4)=(1\,5\,4\,3\,2\,6)$ (I composed cycles from right to left). A $6$-cycle has order $6$, hence 
$$(1\,5\,4\,3\,2\,6)^{1001}=(1\,5\,4\,3\,2\,6)^{1001\bmod 6}= (1\,5\,4\,3\,2\,6)^{-1}=(1\,6\,2\,3\,4\,5).$$

Comment: You should probably mention that you’re following the convention in which cycles are applied from right to left; if the OP is following the opposite convention, $\alpha=(134256)$, though the essentials of the argument are unchanged.

Comment: For me these cycles are mappings, so it's natural.

Comment: But don’t forget, some people compose arbitrary mappings in the opposite order, too, and it’s especially common in this context.

Comment: OK, I'll add that.